# Timepicker, change interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this timepicker in my MVC-project:

```
<div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tid, "Tid (minuter)", new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tid)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tid, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

This lets me choose any number of minutes I want. I would like to change the interval to quarters of an hour..Like 15,30,45,60 etc...where 120 is the "roof". How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

With Java Script.

I suppose there's a property that limits the possibilities.